# Is Data from StarTrek dead?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-data, star-trek-nemesis

At the end of Star Trek: Nemesis Data sacrifies himself by destructing Scimitar(year 2379). I thought he died.
But then i searched for Enterprise F and there I saw written that:

> "Captain Data was offered command of the vessel but refused."
>   *(Year 2409).*

**How is he alive?**

Comment: If you had bothered to click Data's name when you saw that quote on http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-F) , then you could have read http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Data#Turbulent_times .

Comment: No, he is Satan on the new TV series "Outcast". (not really, probably, so that's not a spoiler)